# How to add attachments(.txt, .pdf, .zip, etc) to email using graphapi in java code

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I tried below code, for the first try I try to attach the .txt file.

```
private static void sendMailWithAttachment(String sFrom,String sSubject,String sContent,BodyType sContentType) {
        
         final Message message = new Message();
            message.subject = sSubject;
            message.body = new ItemBody();
            message.body.content = sContent;
            message.body.contentType = sContentType;
            
            LinkedList<Attachment> attachmentsList = new LinkedList<Attachment>();
            FileAttachment fileAttachment = new FileAttachment();
            
            fileAttachment.name = "Example text file";
           // Path path = Paths.get("/Users/user/Desktop/Text.txt");
                        
            fileAttachment.contentBytes = FileUtils.readAllBytes(path);
            
            fileAttachment.oDataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment";
            attachmentsList.add(fileAttachment);
            
            AttachmentCollectionResponse attachmentCollectionResponse = new AttachmentCollectionResponse();
            attachmentCollectionResponse.value = attachmentsList;
            AttachmentCollectionPage attachmentCollectionPage = new AttachmentCollectionPage(attachmentCollectionResponse, null);
            message.attachments = attachmentCollectionPage;
            
              _appClient.users("xxyy@xxyy.com")
                .sendMail(UserSendMailParameterSet
                    .newBuilder()
                    .withMessage(message)
                    .withSaveToSentItems(null)
                    .build())
                .buildRequest()
                .post();
    }
```

I am not understand that how to give the path which takes the attachment from the local system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path "/Users/user/Desktop/Text.txt" appears to be Windows Resource Management

If the program and files are in different drive letters, you can use `Paths.get("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Text.txt")`.

If the program and file are in the same drive letter, you can use `\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Text.txt`

It is recommended to use `java.io.File.separator` as the directory separator to be compatible with different platforms

Comment: Thank you @Jagger Cai  , what is import statement of  Path path = Paths.get("/Users/user/Desktop/Text.txt");   Path and Paths

Comment: java.nio.file.Paths   java.nio.file.Path

Comment: If we want to attaché .pdf file then how can we do that.

Comment: @Mani Bellamkonda  For the `FileUtils.readAllBytes` method, there should be no difference in using txt and pdf as attachments to emails

Comment: but , it is not attaching like .pdf format , after running the code, in mail I see in the from of .txt file. but, I need it in .pdf file..

Comment: With `javax.mail.*` lib, code samples: `MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();`
`textPart.setText("xxx");`

`MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();`
`DataSource source = new FileDataSource("path/to/file.pdf");`
`attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));`
`attachmentPart.setFileName("file.pdf");`

`Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();`
`multipart.addBodyPart(textPart);`
`multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);`

`message.setContent(multipart);`